# Using MongoDB $where to compare elements from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

Let's assume I have two following MongoDB documents:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId(a59b0e19aff8a2ed2128bef97"), 
"name" : "John", 
"matches" : [
    {
        "name" : "Bob", 
        "count" : 10
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "John", 
        "count" : 20
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Alice", 
        "count" : 30
    }
 ]
}


{ 
"_id" : ObjectId(b59b0e19aff8a2ed2128bef97"), 
"name" : "Mike", 
"matches" : [
    {
        "name" : "Bob", 
        "count" : 10
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "John", 
        "count" : 20
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Alice", 
        "count" : 30
    }
 ]
}
```

I need to create MongoDB query that will compare "name" with "matches.name".

In my example only first document will be matched because "John" is in the "matches" Array.
Second document will not be matched because Mike is not in the Array.

I tried `{$where : "this.matches.name == this.name"}` but this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want mongo query or a js code will do? Because if you already have loaded the document in some variable, a js code would be more suitable

Comment: No, I want mongo query. JS solution is simple in this case when documents already loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be what you are looking for, an `aggregate` query looking through `matches.$.name` to see if any match `$name`

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
            "$redact": {
                "$cond": [{
                        "$anyElementTrue": [{
                                "$map": {
                                    "input": "$matches",
                                    "as": "matches",
                                    "in": {
                                        "$eq": ["$$matches.name", "$name"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "$$KEEP",
                    "$$PRUNE"
                ]
            }
        }
        ])
```

Which neatly returns

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c54e6f505e2f07180e60f7"), 
    "name" : "John", 
    "matches" : [
        {
            "name" : "Bob", 
            "count" : 10.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "John", 
            "count" : 20.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Alice", 
            "count" : 30.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Skami. This solution does the job very well!

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this functional query approach ?

```
db.myCollection.find( { $where: function() { return (this.matches.name == this.name) } } );
```

if this is working for your scenario, please comment here :)

Comment: It's same as `{$where : "this.matches.name == this.name"}` and this query doesn't return any documents